# Looping IF statements for each row in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I am new to using pandas coming from a SAS background and I am trying to segment a continuous variable into bands using the following code.

```
var_range = df['BILL_AMT1'].max() - df['BILL_AMT1'].min()
a= 10
for i in range(1,a):
    inc = var_range/a
    lower_bound = df['BILL_AMT1'].min() + (i-1)*inc
    print('Lower bound is '+str(lower_bound))
    upper_bound = df['BILL_AMT1'].max() + (i)*inc
    print('Upper bound is '+str(upper_bound))
    if (lower_bound <= df['BILL_AMT1'] < upper_bound):
        df['bill_class'] = i
    i+=1
```

I am expecting the code to check if the value of `df['BILL_AMT1']` is within the current loops boundings and set a `df['bill_class']` accordingly.

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think that the if condition is evaluating correctly but the error is due to assigning a new column a value of the for loops counter.

Can anyone explain what is going wrong or suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the `ValueError`, change

```
if (lower_bound <= df['BILL_AMT1'] < upper_bound):
    df['bill_class'] = i
```

to

```
mask = (lower_bound <= df['BILL_AMT1']) & (df['BILL_AMT1'] < upper_bound)
df.loc[mask, 'bill_class'] = i
```

---

The [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) `(lower_bound <= df['BILL_AMT1'] < upper_bound)` is equivalent to

```
(lower_bound <= df['BILL_AMT1']) and (df['BILL_AMT1'] < upper_bound)
```

The `and` operator causes the two boolean Series `(lower_bound <= df['BILL_AMT1'])`,  `(df['BILL_AMT1'] < upper_bound)` to be evaluated in a boolean context -- i.e. reduced to a single boolean value. Pandas [refuses to reduce](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas) Series to a single boolean value.

Instead, to return a boolean Series, use the `&` operator instead of `and`:

```
mask = (lower_bound <= df['BILL_AMT1']) & (df['BILL_AMT1'] < upper_bound)
```

and then to assign values to the `bill_class` column where `mask` is True, use `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[mask, 'bill_class'] = i
```

---

To bin the data in `df['BILL_AMT1']`, you could remove the Python `for-loop` entirely, and as [DSM suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854269/looping-if-statements-for-each-row-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/40854439?noredirect=1#comment68925683_40854439), use `pd.cut`:

```
df['bill_class'] = pd.cut(df['BILL_AMT1'], bins=10, labels=False)+1
```

Comment: @DSM: Yes, totally my mistake.

Comment: Much better. :-)  Although we should probably recommend one of the vectorized ways (whether pd.cut or np.digitize -- I see you've already got at least one pd.cut answer to cite..)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the method @DMS suggested as i don't really understand the .loc and mask stuff fully.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should be the fix to your code:

```
mx, mn = df['BILL_AMT1'].max(), df['BILL_AMT1'].min()
rng = mx - mn
a = 10

for i in range(a):
    inc = rng / a
    lower_bound = mn + i * inc
    print('Lower bound is ' + str(lower_bound))
    upper_bound = mn + (i + 1) * inc if i + 1 < a else mx
    print('Upper bound is ' + str(upper_bound))
    ge = df['BILL_AMT1'].ge(lower_bound)
    lt = df['BILL_AMT1'].lt(upper_bound)
    df.loc[ge & lt, 'bill_class'] = i
```

---

***however***
I'd do this

```
df['bill_class'] = pd.qcut(df['BILL_AMT1'], 10, list(range(10)))
```